# Fetch those records whose CREATED_TIME - EVENT_TIME difference should be 12 hour

Tags: oracle

Tried writing a query, Can you help in this.

Fetch those records whose CREATED_TIME - INCIDENT_TIME difference should be 12 hour.

Table details:

[image]

Reffered site : https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:96012348060

many other sites.

I had seen month_between function but didn't found any for hours.

Tried this query which is not working

```
SELECT (CREATED_TIME - INCIDENT_TIME) * 24 > 12  AS hoursBetween
FROM IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. For example, what is your table structure? Can you post some sample data and desired result? What have you tried so far and why it's not working?

Comment: updated the question, let me know if you need any further info

Comment: @Aleksej Need any further info let me know. Any help regarding this query ?

Answer (score 0):

After referring few oracle blogs, got the query

```
select *

from IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR

where 24*(CREATED_TIME - INCIDENT_TIME) < :p_time
```